# Create table using sqlcmd || Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I have a create table statement in a file. Using `sqlcmd` command, I want to create a table. Below is the table structure present in the file `column.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbname].[accessforms].tblename1 
(
     pk_column int PRIMARY KEY, 
     column_1 int NOT NULL
);
GO
```

I run it like this:

```
sqlcmd -S server_name -U username -P password -i /home/usr/columns.sql -o /home/usr/columns.txt
```

And I am getting this error;

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'dbname.accessforms.tblename1' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Could you please help me? Why am I getting this error and how we can solve this?

Comment: A simply search will generally find the answer. Older versions of azure don't support cross-database queries. And that is why is it usually important to specify the version and edition of sql server you are using. But why this complication? Just add the appropriate parameter to your sqlcmd command and remove the database name from your create statement. Let the connection determine the database to use - make your code easier to use.

Comment: I have used database name in sqlcmd and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're running that query in the Cloud.

Azure Cloud doesn't allow three part naming conventions, such as database_name.schema_name.object_name.
You'll have to drop the database name from your reference and only use schema.object.

Your script will have to become:

```
    CREATE TABLE [accessforms].tblename1 
(
     pk_column int PRIMARY KEY, 
     column_1 int NOT NULL
);
GO
```